# jQuery UI combined slider percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, slider

I have taken this example and added 5 sliders on it.

Exemple: http://jsfiddle.net/redsunsoft/caPAb/2/
My Exemple: http://jsfiddle.net/9azJG/

```
    var sliders = $("#sliders .slider");
    var availableTotal = 100;

    sliders.each(function() {
        var init_value = parseInt($(this).text());

        $(this).siblings('.value').text(init_value);

        $(this).empty().slider({
            value: init_value,
            min: 0,
            max: availableTotal,
            range: "max",
            step: 2,
            animate: 0,
            slide: function(event, ui) {

                // Update display to current value
                $(this).siblings('.value').text(ui.value);

                // Get current total
                var total = 0;

                sliders.not(this).each(function() {
                    total += $(this).slider("option", "value");
                });

                // Need to do this because apparently jQ UI
                // does not update value until this event completes
                total += ui.value;

                var delta = availableTotal - total;

                // Update each slider
                sliders.not(this).each(function() {
                    var t = $(this),
                        value = t.slider("option", "value");

                    var new_value = value + (delta/2);

                    if (new_value < 0 || ui.value == 100) 
                        new_value = 0;
                    if (new_value > 100) 
                        new_value = 100;

                    t.siblings('.value').text(new_value);
                    t.slider('value', new_value);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

When there are five sliders present, the jQuery sliders react in a weird way each time the sliders are dragged. It seems like the value for the target sliders goes to zero and back to the original value on each step.

Would anyone know what causes this issue? I have been searching for hours without any idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`delta/n` where **n** = { number of sliders that are under the *main slider* }

```
var new_value = value + (delta/4);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9azJG/2/)**

Comment: I tried with 5, but yes I guess it's 4 li's excluding the current slider in action. Thanks allot!