# Jquery Color Mixer Plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need Color Mixer In `jquery` in which I can mix 3 `color %` wise

Example Like:

```
FinalOutput=green(20%)+Yellow(40%)+ Red(%40%)
```

I need Something Like this Please Help Me.

Thanks

Comment: Have you try to find anything on internet Or tried anything your self to creating it?

Comment: i tried lots of time but i could not find correct

Comment: might be this [stackoverflow link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21774519/mix-more-than-2-colors-together-with-javascript) and this [xcolor link](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-color-plugin-xcolor/) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Idea 1**

If you use [RGB colors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors.asp):

Create a function that calculates the colors. Eg. Red 100% = 255, Green 100% = 255, Blue 100% = 255. So you need a distribution of 1% and 2.55 color.

For UI it all up to you, a cool slider demo [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17265235/5847011) (the first slider).

**Idea 2**

If I were you I would rather use a good developed colorpicker. Eg. [Eyecon](http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/), [Spectrum](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/).